# Display all pdf files in a folder using MuPdf

Tags: android, android-viewpager, mupdf

With the below code I'm able to display the pdf file by specifying its path.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"sample/pdf/Page2.pdf";          
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path); 
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MuPDFActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the /sample/pdf/ folder I've few pdf files.

How can I display all the pdf files as viewpager using MuPdf?

I need the pdf view as below.

[image]